# Is there an API that returns the URL for the Office 365 Delve home page for a user?

Tags: office365, delve

In Office 365 Delve, each user has a "home" page. For the logged in user, the page has a URL like https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx and for people that the logged in user is connected to, the URL looks like https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx?u=c6438bc0-b956-4ff8-9386-9fab87639678&p=friend1%40contoso.onmicrosoft.com&v=work.

Is there a way to obtain these URL's programmatically via an API call (i.e. without constructing the URL on your own by string manipulation)?

Answer (score 0):

When you search for a person using the SharePoint Search REST interface, the path managed property returns a URL that redirects to the above URL. However, at some point, you need to know the target user's tenant name so it would seem to me that doing a string replace on the URL you already mentioned would be the simplest approach.